# Using nginx $http_referer to use different static assets

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to deploy two different versions of same app on the same nginx-based server. If the URL starts with /v2, then "v2" should be used, otherwise use v1. Example:

```
http://example.com/v2/x/y/z          * runs v2 app
http://example.com/anything/else     * runs v1 app
```

The two different versions of the app are proxied through nginx, and that piece works well.

The issue is that I have two directories of static assets, `/static` and `/cachedassets`, that are common to both versions (and both rooted from `/home/v1|2/www/public`. So, even though a request to `http://example.com/v2/x/y/z` will initially use the right app, the page that loads will contain references to `/static` and `/cachedassets`, without the /v2 prefix, that will incorrectly load from `/home/v1/www/public`.

I know referer is an imperfect solution. As a temporary stopgap, until I have a chance to craft a more robust solution, I'm trying to use nginx's $http_referer to point to the correct location for these assets. Here's the nginx file:

```
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4
    server_name example.com

    ...

    location /v2 {
      root /home/v2/www/public;

      try_files $uri @proxyv2;
      access_log off;
      expires max;
    }

    location ^/(static|cachedassets) {
      root /home/v1/www/public;

      if ($http_referer ~* "/v2/") {
        root /home/v2/www/public;
      }
    }

    location / {
       root /home/v1/www/public;

       try_files $uri @proxyv1;
       access_log off;
       expires max;
    }

    location @proxyv1 {
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/v1-www.sock;
       uwsgi_modifier1 5;
    }

    location @proxyv2 {
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/v2-www.sock;
       uwsgi_modifier1 5;
    }

    ...

}
```

Any thoughts?

Bonus points for a solution where I can easily specify several "v2" prefixes. For example, here I might specify v2, versiontwo, and vtwo, and the following URLs would all invoke the v2 app:

```
http://www.example.com/v2/something
http://www.example.com/versiontwo/abc
http://www.example.com/vtwo/abc/def/ghi
```

and of course, `http://www.example.com/somethingelse` would run v1.

I'm also open to other ideas that don't use http_referer to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than `if` blocks, use a `map` variable to set the `root`. The `map` can contain a number of arbitrarily complex regular expressions. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.

For example:

```
map $http_referer $root {
    default   "/home/v1/www/public";
    ~*/v2/    "/home/v2/www/public";
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/(static|cachedassets) {
        root $root;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works well, thanks!  One small note: Should be `location ~ ^/(static ... ` -- I left out the tilde `~` in the original question.

Comment: I wonder if a similar `map` construct exists for the different proxies?

Comment: You can use variables for a `proxy_pass` domain name as long as a `resolver` is defined (I am not sure if it works for unix sockets syntax). It will be evaluated for each request, so will be less efficient than a constant value.